# How to change multiple same name input element in Wordpress post with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, post

I can change Wordpress input element with different name. As for example the following input element:

```html
<input class="wpProQuiz_button" type="button" value="Start Quiz" name="startQuiz">
```

can be changed with the following jQuery code:

```js
jQuery("input[name='startQuiz']").attr("value", "Start Mock Test");
```

**Question:**

How can I do the same for the following with  same name input element in Wordpress?

```html
<input type="button" name="next" value="Next" class="wpProQuiz_button wpProQuiz_QuestionButton" style="float: right;">

<input type="button" name="next" value="Quiz-summary" class="wpProQuiz_button wpProQuiz_QuestionButton" style="float: right;">
```

I have use the following for the above two input element like :

```js
jQuery("input[name='next']").attr("value", "Next");
jQuery("input[name='next']").attr("value", "Test-summary");
```

But it is not working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery selectors:

jQuery("input[name='next']:first-child").val("zzzz");
jQuery("input[name='next']:nth-child(2)").val("qqqqq");

and take in mind "float:right" :)

more examples here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/child-filter-selectors/

Comment: @ VladimirMiroshnichenko "jQuery("input[name='next']:first-child").val("zzzz"); "  and   " jQuery("input[name='next']:nth-child(2)").val("qqqqq");" are not working.